# How to measure the total number of cells in an average human body?

Tags: cell-biology, homework, biophysics

I have got one assignment to calculate the approximate sum total of all cells in the human body. How to tackle this problem? I know that the current statistics is $10^{13}$ cells. I wanted some hints.

Comment: @kmm Actually I don't know where to start.

Comment: yes I calculated it by dividing the volumes. Volume of average human body / avg. volume of a mammalian cell. Around 10^14 cells.

Comment: So that's larger by only one order of magnitude. Not that bad for a rough approximation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic [Fermi estimation problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_estimate). The usual approach is to estimate the volume of a body, estimate the volume of a cell, and divide one by the other, remembering of course to have both volumes in the same units.

My quick attempt gave 10<sup>13</sup> to the nearest order of magnitude.